# Admob not show in lollipop 5.1 device

Tags: android, admob, ads

hello friends i wnat ot integrate admob in my application so i set following code for that

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity{

 AdView adView;
 RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutRoot;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.advs);
    mRelativeLayoutRoot=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);


    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_unit_id));
    adView.setId(11);
    LayoutParams lp;
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // You might want to tweak these to WRAP_CONTENT
    lp.addRule(mRelativeLayoutRoot.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    mRelativeLayoutRoot.addView(adView, lp);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

}

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

When i run above code advertisement show only **Jellybean** , **kitkat** mobile device in **Lolliop device 5.1** it is not showing any idea how can i solve this problem ?

**EDIT**

When i run this cod ein **Micomax android one phone (Lollipop 5.1)** it is not show advertise on that

Comment: have you test on device or emulator ?

Comment: Haresh Chhelana Yes i tested samsung galaxy grand qutroo(Jelly Bean), sumsang galaxy core 2 SM-G355H (Kitkat)

Comment: Haresh Chhelana : See my edit portion i m facing problem in that device

Comment: i think this might be device related issue not OS.

Comment: But how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you start by creating your AdView in the XML layout for your Activity rather than in code. It will help eliminate a few potential errors.

Next, make sure that you have added the deviceIds for the 2 devices as test device ids.

Finally, look at your logcat for the 2 devices and see what the Admob log says in the case when the ad does not load.