# How to load Admob ad whenever it's possible?

Tags: android, admob

Ad shows only if WI-FI was enabled before app start (it won't appear if wi-fi was enabled during app session). How to load Admob ad whenever it's possible? I believe, it's got something to do with AdListener.
My current code:

```
   adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdLoaded() {
           adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           super.onAdLoaded();
       }

       public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
           adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   });
```

Comment: Please checkout this link hope it will help you..
[Admob][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213313/admob-not-show-in-lollipop-5-1-device/30213955#30213955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a BroadCastReceiver to know when the network status has changed so you can load your adds.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static final int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static final int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI = 1;
public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE = 2;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int status = getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    if ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (status == NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i("Receiver","not connected");

        } else {
            Log.i("Receiver","connected");
            //If the connectivity changes while using the app and it is connected to a network you can load your adds.
            AddListener.initialiseAds(mAdView, adRequest);
        }
    }
}

public int getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = getConnectivityStatus(context);
    int status = 0;
    if (conn == TYPE_WIFI ) {
        status = NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI;
    } else if (conn == TYPE_MOBILE ) {
        status = NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE;
    } else if (conn == TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
    return status;
}

public int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}}
```

Then we have the AddListener class

```
public final class AddListener {

private AddListener(){
}

public static void initialiseAds(final AdView mAdView, AdRequest adRequest) {
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (mAdView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            Log.i("Receiver","Add loaded");
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("Receiver","Add error "+errorCode);
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Log.i("Receiver","Add opened");
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Log.i("Receiver","Add left app");
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Log.i("Receiver","Add closed");
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });
}}
```

And from the MainUI class we do this:

```
public class MainUI extends AppCompatActivity {

...
public static AdView mAdView;
public static AdRequest adRequest;
...

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mAdView!=null){  // Check if Adview is not null in case of fist time load.
        mAdView.resume();}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
        Log.i("pause","pause view");
    }
    super.onPause();
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_ui);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.
            Builder()
            .addTestDevice("DDF43F508E61CBB2ACA96D879C66AB42")
            .build();
    AddListener.initialiseAds(mAdView,adRequest);

    ...} }
```

Also remember to register your BroadcastReceiver in your Manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".utils.NetworkTools.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And ask for these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I wish you could tell me why the down vote, i did this and it worked fine on my app

Comment: After searching I found that on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667164/admob-does-not-refresh-the-ad-after-hiding-showing-adview someone already asked something similar to this and the accepted answer is very similar to what I placed here so I don´t understand why the down vote, please someone clarify.

Comment: i think someone downvoted because it's an old question

Comment: The Ads visibility does not change when the network connection is ON / OFF when the App is running. It only checks on APP start.. How to change Ads visibility when the network connection changes, when the user is inside the APP..

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to know, shall I load the ad or not based on the conditions required for the ad is satisfied like internet and `GooglePlayServices`, then you can use the method below:

```
public static boolean shouldLoadAd(Context context) {
        return (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS && isNetworkAvailable(context));
    }

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

The method shouldLoadAd checks if internet and Googleplayservices is available then load ad else dont load ad, if it returns false you can hide the adView.